# Apache2 Multiple SSL certificates with subdomains won't work

Tags: apache, ssl, encryption, debian

I have an Apache 2 server with 2 connected domains. I use certificates from Let's Encrypt. My problem however is, that only the certificate for the first domain works (1.webpage.com). SSL however works for both domains.
This is my config file

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName 1.webpage.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    SSLEngine on
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/1.webpage.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/1.webpage.com/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName 2.webpage.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/2

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/2.webpage.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/2.webpage.com/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Cheers

Comment: If it works now (judging by your deleted answer), you can delete your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a [`NameVirtualHost`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost) directive.

```
NameVirtualHost *:443
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName 1.webpage.com
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```